# Apply Doob's inequality to Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_n$ be a brownian motion, apply Doob's inequality to show that:

$$\mathbb E\left(\sup_{\sigma \leq t \leq \tau} \left(\frac{B_t}{t}\right)^2\right)\leq \frac{4\tau}{\sigma^2}.$$

I know a result about Doob's inequality:

$$\mathbf{P} \left[ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} B_{t} \geq C \right] \leq \exp \left( - \frac{C^2}{2T} \right).$$

But I don't know how to apply.

Comment: Replace $t$ with $t - \sigma$, use stationarity

Comment: I think that:  $E(sup_{\sigma \leq t \leq \tau} (\frac{B_t}{t})^2)\leq E(\frac{(B_\tau)^2}{\tau ^2})\leq \frac{4\tau}{\sigma^2}$. It is right?

Comment: There is another Doob's inequality, one about the expectations of supremum of submartingales. That one might be more relevant here.